# Why isless(0 , missing) returns true but 0<missing returns missing in Julia?

Tags: julia

I encountered a strange behavior from Julia today, and that's when I tried to compare `missing` with `0`! If you try this `0<missing` in REPL:

```
julia> 0<missing
missing
```

But if you try to use pre-built `isless` function like this:

```
julia> isless(0 , missing)
true
```

It's strange because `0<missing` means `0 is less than missing` same as `isless(0 , missing)`. According to `isless` documentation:

> isless(t1::Tuple, t2::Tuple)
> Returns true when t1 is less than t2 in lexicographic order.

Shouldn't `0<missing` return `true` as well?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`missing < 0` produces `missing` because `<` is a "standard" comparison operator.

Now consider a question: is `missing` less than `0`? The answer is: we do not know. `missing` stands for some unknown value - it can be greater or less than `0`. Therefore `missing < 0` produces `missing`.

As you can see in the documentation of `<`:

> this operator implements a partial order.

This means that it does not guarantee that all values are comparable. A similar  (but not identical) situation is with `NaN`:

```
julia> NaN < 0.0
false

julia> NaN > 0.0
false

julia> NaN == 0.0
false
```

Also notice that although `-0.0` and `0.0` are different floating point values we have:

```
julia> -0.0 < 0.0
false
```

---

Now let us discuss `isless`. It is needed because sometimes you want an operator that defines total order, as you can see in its documentation:

> Test whether `x` is less than `y`, according to a fixed total order (defined together with `isequal`).

This is useful in cases you want to make sure that you can safely assume that every value is comparable. For example `sort` uses `isless`.

Now in order to make sure `isless` defines total order we need to define how `missing` is positioned in this total order. It was decided that `missing` is larger than any other value. Therefore `isless(missing, 0)` is `false`. Of course this is an arbitrary decision. It was made so that e.g. when you `sort`
a vector `missing` is put at the end:

```
julia> sort([1, missing, 2])
3-element Vector{Union{Missing, Int64}}:
 1
 2
  missing
```

which is what people usually want.

Now notice the behavior of `NaN` and `-0.0`:

```
julia> isless(NaN, missing)
true

julia> isless(Inf, NaN)
true

julia> isless(-0.0, 0.0)
true
```

So as you can see `NaN` is greater than `Inf` but less than `missing` and `-0.0` is less than `0.0`. Again - since `isless` is a total order so distinct values have to be put in a distinct place in this total order.

Answer (score 3):

From the doc:

> Standard equality and comparison operators follow the propagation rule
> presented above: if any of the operands is missing, the result is
> missing.

```
julia> missing < 1
missing

julia> 2 >= missing
missing
```

And then, a bit below:

> The isless operator is another exception: missing is considered as
> greater than any other value. This operator is used by sort, which
> therefore places missing values after all other values.

```
julia> isless(1, missing)
true

julia> isless(missing, Inf)
false

julia> isless(missing, missing)
false
```

So this seems to be by design:
https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/missing/#Propagation-of-Missing-Values

Now if your question is why this has been designed like this, then perhaps Julia's designers will stop by to enlighten us :)

Comment: Thanks for your response, But I asked, *Shouldn't `0<missing` return `true` as well?* I don't know how your answer is related to the question. I know that [`missing` is considered as greater than any other value](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/missing/#:~:text=missing%20is%20considered%20as%20greater%20than%20any%20other%20value.). Can you please explain more?

Comment: See edit. It's also in the same doc. This is by design. The relevant section is [Propagation of missing values](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/missing/#Propagation-of-Missing-Values)